# libcurl - get content_type data (not free pointer)

Tags: c, libcurl

Please tell me one moment related to the option CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE:

```
char *cont_type_pointer = NULL;
curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE, &cont_type_pointer );
```

> The "cont_type_pointer" pointer will be NULL or pointing to private memory you MUST NOT
> free it - it gets freed when you call curl_easy_cleanup on the
> corresponding CURL handle.

This thing is unclear: "you MUST NOT free it - it gets freed when you call curl_easy_cleanup"

And if after this request I do not call curl_easy_cleanup() and immediately make another request in which I also need to get data CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE ?? Will it be a memory leak ?

The memory from the last request was not released by the "cont_type_pointer" pointer, and I am already making the second request.
It's not clear.

Comment: Try it and run your program through valgrind to see if it reports a leak?

Comment: "you MUST NOT free it" is very very clear, and the subsequent "it gets freed when you call curl_easy_cleanup" explains why you mustn't free it. Given the clarity of those two phrases, I'd assume that I don't have to call curl_easy_cleanup() immediately, but when I do then all allocated memory would be released. If the docs said "it gets freed when you call curl_easy_cleanup AND YOU MUST DO THAT BEFORE MAKING ANOTHER CALL" then that also would be clear, but it doesn't say that so no need to immediately clean up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `libcurl` is an OpenSource project, we could easilly check that ourself. `curl_easy_getinfo` with the flag `CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE` [just returns](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/3085ccfae996bb0fa606d2c7bc6783dc15d76a30/lib/getinfo.c) internal field from the `CURL*` struct:

```
case CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE:
    *param_charp = data->info.contenttype;
```

Hence the requirement not to free its memory after use.

According to the [Curl documentation](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_perform.html) you are even encouraged for multiple `curl_easy_perform` calls to share existing connection and calling `curl_easy_cleanup` only after everything is done:

> You can do any amount of calls to curl_easy_perform while using the
> same easy_handle. If you intend to transfer more than one file, you
> are even encouraged to do so. libcurl will then attempt to re-use the
> same connection for the following transfers, thus making the
> operations faster, less CPU intense and using less network resources.
> Just note that you will have to use curl_easy_setopt between the
> invokes to set options for the following curl_easy_perform.

If you look deep inside `curl_easy_perform` you can see, that `libcurl` uses internal linked list to store connection data from all calls. When you finally call `curl_easy_cleanup` all memory will be cleaned and there will be no leak.